# How to use POST method in Drupal 8 Views Rest Export?

Tags: rest, api, post, drupal, get

Drupal 8 supports REST API exports in GET method. But How can define POST method in views rest export api? #Drupal8 #views

Comment: i would say drupal sees can't achieve this simple thing

Answer (score 0):

By its nature, views deliver information from the database to the user. They are not designed to take in data.
To be able to accept POST requests, activate module RESTful Web Services and REST UI.
[image: The Rest UI]
The Rest UI

[image]
Editing a resource in the Rest UI

Doing so, you'll create endpoints for accepting POST data.